# Jest testing: custom currency/decimal formatters showed wrong delimiters

Tags: reactjs, decimal, delimiter, jestjs

I tried to switch to Jest-testing inside of our React application.
Lots of mocha and enzyme tests are working with small fixes.

With tests for a currency formatting component I get the wrong culture format inside the tests. I expect the result to be in format:

> 1.234.567,89 €

but I receive:

> 1,234,567.89 €

In the application I get all values formatted nicely in German formats as expected.

**BTW:**
Inside of a helper method we use following code for internal formatting

```
value.toLocaleString(['de-DE'], {
    style: 'decimal',
    useGrouping: true,
    minimumFractionDigits: 2,
    maximumFractionDigits: 2
})
```

Answer (score 3):

I've got it...

Because Jest is using Node for testing and Node doesn't support other locales than 'en', I need to add Intl/IntlPolyfill inside a Jest setup file.

```
const areIntlLocalesSupported = require('intl-locales-supported');

const localesMyAppSupports = [
    'de'
];

if (global.Intl) {

    // Determine if the built-in `Intl` has the locale data we need. 
    if (!areIntlLocalesSupported(localesMyAppSupports)) {
        // `Intl` exists, but it doesn't have the data we need, so load the 
        // polyfill and patch the constructors we need with the polyfill's. 
        const IntlPolyfill = require('intl');
        Intl.NumberFormat = IntlPolyfill.NumberFormat;
        Intl.DateTimeFormat = IntlPolyfill.DateTimeFormat;

        Number.prototype.toLocaleString = IntlPolyfill.__localeSensitiveProtos.Number.toLocaleString;
        Date.prototype.toLocaleString = IntlPolyfill.__localeSensitiveProtos.Date.toLocaleString;

    }

} else {
    // No `Intl`, so use and load the polyfill. 
    global.Intl = require('intl');
}
```

I don't know the reason, but I need to explicitly overwrite `Number.prototype.toLocaleString` and `Date.prototype.toLocaleString`.